# System.FormatException was unhandled

Tags: c#-4.0

In form load i'm updating Drop Down List Value
ddlFont:

```
foreach (FontFamily font in System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families)
{
    ddlFont.Items.Add(font.Name);
}
```

ddlFontSize:

```
for (int i = 8; i < 24; i++)
{
    ddlFontSize.Items.Add(i.ToString().Trim());
}
```

ddlFontStyle:

```
ddlFontStyle.Items.Add(System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold.ToString());
ddlFontStyle.Items.Add(System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic.ToString());
ddlFontStyle.Items.Add(System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular.ToString());
```

ddlFontColor:

```
ddlColor.Items.Add(System.Drawing.Color.Black.Name.ToString());
ddlColor.Items.Add(System.Drawing.Color.Blue.Name.ToString());
ddlColor.Items.Add(System.Drawing.Color.Green.Name.ToString());
ddlColor.Items.Add(System.Drawing.Color.Red.Name.ToString());
ddlColor.Items.Add(System.Drawing.Color.White.Name.ToString());
ddlColor.Items.Add(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow.Name.ToString());
```

If user change the Font, size, style, color then i must change RichTextBox control text font, size, style, color.

I call the "FontFormation" method from `SelectedIndexChanged` event of Drop Down List controls which is having Font Name ddl, Font Style ddl, Font Size ddl.

```
    private void ddlFont_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FontFormation();
    }
```

In my code first two conditions are executing without error but last one alone showing `"Input string was not in a correct format"` error at `ddlFont.Text`.

```
public void FontFormation()
{
    if (FontStyle.Bold.ToString() == ddlFontStyle.Text)
    {
        rchtxtMainBody.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(ddlFont.Text, Convert.ToUInt32(ddlFontSize.Text), FontStyle.Bold);
    }
    else if(FontStyle.Italic.ToString() == ddlFontStyle.Text)
    {
        rchtxtMainBody.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(ddlFont.Text, Convert.ToUInt32(ddlFontSize.Text), FontStyle.Italic);
    }
    else if (FontStyle.Regular.ToString() == ddlFontStyle.Text)
    {
        rchtxtMainBody.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(ddlFont.Text, Convert.ToUInt32(ddlFontSize.Text), FontStyle.Regular);
    }
}
```

If i remove my last else if condition i.e `FontStyle.Regular.ToString() == ddlFontStyle.Text` then code is getting executed without any error.

Comment: What's in your ddlFontSize.Text then? Is it "12px" or "12pt" or just "12"?

Comment: Update your question with some examples of what you have in your DropDowns. That makes debugging easier. Try to run the Convert.ToUint32 by itself and see if it throws another exception

Comment: I've updated my question. Plz check the information, is this enough or not? My intention is user can Highlight the particular text in RichTextBox with selected font, color, style, size.

Comment: Yes, that update contains enough information for people to start figuring out what could be wrong. :) You can always use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) to see if you can find the error more easily. It's a code scratchpad.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your ddlFontSize.Text. The exception occurs when it cannot convert in to UInt32. Please debug your code and make sure that ddlFontSize.Text doesn't have "px" or "pt" with and and its only a number in string format.

Comment: As you denoted, ddlFontSize does not having any "px" or "pt". Just values alone exist such as 11 12 13